# When I reload page values don't change, they only do when I log in

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, I want when the user reloads the page his statistics to change based on the database.
For example, let's say that I just registered and my statistics are Money-0, Diamond-0, Ruby-0 and then somehow I added 10 money to the user.
Now, what I want is the user to be able to see his new statistics(Money-10, Diamond-0, Ruby-0) only when he decides to reload the page.

I have added onload function to the body, but it doesn't seem to work.
The user statistics only change when the user logs out and then logs in again.

index2.php(Where the user statistics should be displayed)

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>PwettyKittyPincesa</title>

  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script>
    function getUserStats(){
        <?php
            $queryThree = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE username='$username'";
            $userStats = mysqli_query($db,$queryThree);
            while($userStatsTwo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userStats)){
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $userStatsTwo['ID'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $userStatsTwo['username'];
                $_SESSION['diamonds'] = $userStatsTwo['diamonds'];
                $_SESSION['ruby'] = $userStatsTwo['ruby'];
                $_SESSION['money'] = $userStatsTwo['money'];
                $_SESSION['level'] = $userStatsTwo['level'];
            };
        ?>
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="getUserStats()">
    <div class="navWrapper">
        <div class="statistics">
            <div class="profilePicture" name="profilePicture">
                <label class="profilePictureLabel" for="profilePicture"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="money" name="money">
                <label class="rubyLabel" for="ruby"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['money']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="diamond" name="diamond">
                <label class="diamondLabel" for="diamond"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['diamonds']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="ruby" name="ruby">
                <label class="rubyLabel" for="ruby"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['ruby']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="level" name="level">
                <label class="levelLabel" for="level"><b>Level:<?php echo $_SESSION['level']; ?></b></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: from where did you got value of `$username`  in your query ?

Comment: @Swati from the server.php file 
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

Comment: so, that `username` is coming from different page,that's the reason `onreload` the value doesn't change , you need to store these values in `session` and then used it in your `query`.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't need any javascript to achieve this. You can run all your session assignments at the top of the document. Also, you'll need to include `session_start()` at the very top of the document to ensure the session variables become global values. However, if you do not need to use these values across other pages, then you can just use standard variables to store the data instead of storing it in a session.

This is using session variables:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('server.php');

$queryThree = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE username='$username'";
$userStats = mysqli_query($db,$queryThree);
while($userStatsTwo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userStats)){
  $_SESSION['userid'] = $userStatsTwo['ID'];
  $_SESSION['username'] = $userStatsTwo['username'];
  $_SESSION['diamonds'] = $userStatsTwo['diamonds'];
  $_SESSION['ruby'] = $userStatsTwo['ruby'];
  $_SESSION['money'] = $userStatsTwo['money'];
  $_SESSION['level'] = $userStatsTwo['level'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>PwettyKittyPincesa</title>

  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navWrapper">
        <div class="statistics">
            <div class="profilePicture" name="profilePicture">
                <label class="profilePictureLabel" for="profilePicture"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="money" name="money">
                <label class="rubyLabel" for="ruby"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['money']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="diamond" name="diamond">
                <label class="diamondLabel" for="diamond"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['diamonds']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="ruby" name="ruby">
                <label class="rubyLabel" for="ruby"><b><?php echo $_SESSION['ruby']; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="level" name="level">
                <label class="levelLabel" for="level"><b>Level:<?php echo $_SESSION['level']; ?></b></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is using variables:

```
<?php
include('server.php');

$queryThree = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE username='$username'";
$userStats = mysqli_query($db,$queryThree);
while($userStatsTwo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userStats)){
  $userid = $userStatsTwo['ID'];
  $username = $userStatsTwo['username'];
  $diamonds = $userStatsTwo['diamonds'];
  $ruby = $userStatsTwo['ruby'];
  $money = $userStatsTwo['money'];
  $level = $userStatsTwo['level'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>PwettyKittyPincesa</title>

  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navWrapper">
        <div class="statistics">
            <div class="profilePicture" name="profilePicture">
                <label class="profilePictureLabel" for="profilePicture"><b><?php echo $username; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="money" name="money">
                <label class="rubyLabel" for="ruby"><b><?php echo $money; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="diamond" name="diamond">
                <label class="diamondLabel" for="diamond"><b><?php echo $diamonds; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="ruby" name="ruby">
                <label class="rubyLabel" for="ruby"><b><?php echo $ruby; ?></b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="level" name="level">
                <label class="levelLabel" for="level"><b>Level:<?php echo $level; ?></b></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```